# "Replace" VS "Substitute" (For good / For a short while)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I have read somewhere that the verb "replace" should be used for a long term or permanent changes (perhaps those which are forever,) while the verb "substitute" has an implication of being short term or temporary.

But I would like to argue this point as I think I have read many examples and heard many conversations in which native speakers do not observe such rules themselves! The question is that whether I misunderstood them or they do not observe such rules or there is no such a distinction at all.

Let me clarify my meaning by making two related examples and ask you which choices sound incorrect and why?

**Example #1:**

- > ______________while I'm away on vacation (I will return).

**a.** I will replace with another teacher 
**b.** Another teacher will substitute for me

**Example #2:**

- > I had a terrible quarrel with the CEO of the company yesterday, and I am sure that they will _____________ ASAP.

**a.** replace me with another person 
**b.** substitute another person for me

So, to me both options work naturally and idiomatically and I think there is no particular nuance between them.

However, please kindly enlighten me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1: I'd say substitute, because it is temporary.

Example 2: I'd say replace, because it is permanent.

In some contexts, replace and substitute can be virtually identical. For example, when cooking you might "replace" or "substitute" ground turkey for ground beef. The result is the same.

In some industries the concept of a "substitute" is very common, and explicitly temporary. A substitute teacher is never expected to have the job permanently. Even if they become a "long term sub" it is absolutely expected that the primary teacher will come back.

Sports is a context where both "substitutes" and "replacements" exist. They might have some overlap, but again they are usually different. If Johnson replaces Smith in the starting lineup he will be there until further notice. If Johnson substitutes for Smith in a game then Smith will be back in his spot later or in the next game.

There are circumstances where someone might use "replace" for a temporary situation. For example "I'll replace her until she gets back from vacation". It sounds slightly awkward, but not terrible. But to my ear using "substitute" for a permanent change (as in your second example) sounds extremely strange.